# Ensure the static keys exist on another class

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to ensure that all the properties from one class exist in another.

```
export class Components {
    static [Pages.home] = Home.Page
    static [Pages.login] = Login.Page
    static [Pages.logout] = Logout.Page
    static [Pages.dashboardManage] = DashboardManage.Page
    static [Pages.dashboardOrganizationTable] = DashboardOrganizationTable.Page
    static [Pages.organizationSettings] = OrganizationSettings.Page
}

export class Resolvers implements Components {
    static [Pages.home] = Home.Page
    static [Pages.login] = Login.Page
    static [Pages.logout] = Logout.Page
    static [Pages.dashboardManage] = DashboardManage.Page
    static [Pages.dashboardOrganizationTable] = DashboardOrganizationTable.Page
    static [Pages.organizationSettings] = OrganizationSettings.Page
}
```

`implements Components` does not work

I tried this as well:

```
type PagesInUse = keyof typeof Components
type ExmapB = {[key in PagesInUse]: any}
```

Comment: Why do these key names need to be chosen dynamically?

Comment: I simply want whatever is in one class to be required in the other.

Comment: Is there a reason you've made these classes instead of objects? A class with only static members is basically an object.

Answer (score 2):

This works for regular objects:

```
export const Components = {
    [Pages.home]: Home.Page,
    [Pages.login]: Login.Page,
    [Pages.logout]: Logout.Page,
    [Pages.dashboardManage]: DashboardManage.Page,
    [Pages.dashboardOrganizationTable]: DashboardOrganizationTable.Page,
    [Pages.organizationSettings]: OrganizationSettings.Page,
}

type PageKeysInUse = keyof typeof Components
type PagesInUse = { [key in PageKeysInUse]: any }

export const Resolvers: PagesInUse = {
    [Pages.home]: Home.Page,
    [Pages.login]: Login.Page,
    [Pages.logout]: Logout.Page,
    [Pages.dashboardManage]: DashboardManage.Page,
    [Pages.dashboardOrganizationTable]: DashboardOrganizationTable.Page,
    [Pages.organizationSettings]: OrganizationSettings.Page,
}
```